# r kable replace 0.0 with blank or "-" and keep it as numeric

Tags: r, numeric, zero, kable

I have this little table:

```
cases <- c("1182025", "+19525")
deceased <- c("7639", "+25")
TI_7  <- c(1100.395332, 0.0)
    
df <- data.frame(cases, deceased, TI_7)
```

If I kable it, the 0.0 in the third column should not appear.
If possible, the data type of the third column should remain numeric, otherwise `decimal.mark = ','` does not work.

This is how I kable:

```
kbl(df, format.args = list(decimal.mark = ',', digits=6), align = "rccc") %>%
  kable_paper(bootstrap_options = "striped", full_width = F, position = "left")
```

[image]

I tried it with gsub, but then all the 0s disappear, inside the numbers too.

With other functions the data type changes to unknown.

Answer (score 1):

Ok this seems to work:

```
df <- na_if(df, 0)
options(knitr.kable.NA = '')

kbl(df, format.args = list(decimal.mark = ',', digits=6), align = "rccc") %>%
  kable_paper(bootstrap_options = "striped", full_width = F, position = "left")
```